# 3-column responsive layout with middle column top

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive

I have an old 3 column website where the middle column 2 contains the important content (of varying size).

Is it possible using CSS alone (i.e. the template is untouched), to make it responsive such that on narrow screens, the order (top to bottom) becomes Col-2 then Col-1, then Col-3? ie.

Template:

```
<div class="col-1">Left Sidebar</div>
<div class="col-2">Main content</div>
<div class="col-3">Right sidebar</div>
```

I'd like media queries on smaller screen widths to display as:

```
Main content

Left Sidebar

Right sidebar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that using flexbox: In the media queries, you assign `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` to the container (if there is no container / parent element, that's  the `body` tag), and assign the `order` settings (numbers) to the single items according to your desired order as shown below:

```css
body { 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.col-1 {
  order: 2;
  }
.col-2 {
  order: 1;
  }
.col-3 {
  order: 3;
  }
```

```html
<div class="col-1">Left Sidebar</div>
<div class="col-2">Main content</div>
<div class="col-3">Right sidebar</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, exactly what I was looking for, and described more full in:
A Complete Guide to Flexbox
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Do you know whether this works with layouts that use tables that are three cells wide?

Comment: no, that's a flexbox feature, and flexbox can't be combined with tables